# С помощью javascript с одного сайта делать alert на другом сайте

Tags: javascript, iframe

С помощью javascript с одного сайта делать alert на другом сайте?

Сайт 1 содержит нужный код

Сайт 2 изменяется с помощью кода Сайт 1

Оба сайта на php.

Есть ли способы? Возможно ли через iframe?

Comment: В данных темах рассматривали похожую проблему: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139953/displaying-an-alert-box-inside-an-iframe-in-an-html-page,        2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/calling-a-parent-window-function-from-an-iframe

Answer (score 1):

Политика безопасности браузеров позволяет JS коду работать только с данными / DOM с того же домена – см. [Правила ограничения домена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0). Если же вы непременно хотите из фрейма, загруженного с Сайта1 менять элементы в фрейме с Сайта2 – см. [CORS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Ещё вариант – использовать [`window.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) для связи между двумя песочницами разных доменов: на Сайте 2 слушать сообщения, из Сайта 1 их передавать – данные, не код.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, нельзя. Но можно через curl отправить запрос на другой сервер, а на нем в свою очередь этот запрос обработать и выдать соответствующий эксепшн. Еще вам для этого понадобится jQuery.